# C# - xmldoc.selectSingleNode(xpath, nsmanager) returns null

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, xml-parsing, namespaces

I have a Soap envelope which is being used  as request packet for a webservice.
I am setting the nodes values dynamically using the values from a grid
xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath, oManager).InnerXml  = r.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

My xml packet is :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   <s:Body>
    <CardActivation xmlns="www.testclient.com">
      <requestData xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices.DTO" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <LoginUser xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">testuser</LoginUser>
        <UserPassword xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">Testped</UserPassword>
        <IPAddress xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">10.211.1.22</IPAddress>
        <UniqueIDFlag xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">0</UniqueIDFlag>
        <UniqueID xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">1234567890123457502</UniqueID>
        <Source xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">WS</Source>
        <APIVersion xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">1.2</APIVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">1</ApplicationVersion>
        <CallerID xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">221221</CallerID>
        <CalledID xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">3333</CalledID>
        <SessionID xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">221111</SessionID>
        <ANI i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices" />
        <DNS i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices" />
        <Language i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices" />
        <RequestDate xmlns="http://schemas.testdata.org/2004/07/ClientServices">2014-10-08T00:00:00</RequestDate>
        <d4p1:CardNumber i:nil="true" />
        <d4p1:ProxyNumber>1123</d4p1:ProxyNumber>
        <d4p1:CardExpiryDate>2105</d4p1:CardExpiryDate>
      </requestData>
    </CardActivation>   </s:Body> </s:Envelope>
```

When I am trying to set value to UserPassword node, selectSingleNode is returning null. My namespacemanger code is as follows.

```
public static XmlNamespaceManager getAllNamespaces(XmlDocument xDoc)
        {
            XmlNamespaceManager result = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);

           IDictionary<string, string> localNamespaces = null;
            XPathNavigator xNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
            while (xNav.MoveToFollowing(XPathNodeType.Element))
            {
                localNamespaces = xNav.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.Local);
                //  localNamespaces = xNav.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.All);
                foreach (var localNamespace in localNamespaces)
                {
                    string prefix = localNamespace.Key;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
                        prefix = "DEFAULT";

                    result.AddNamespace(prefix, localNamespace.Value);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Do I need to explicitly change my xpath to add prefixes to my default namespace? Is there any approach to do this dynamically -adding prefixes to each node using the namespacemanager? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue without doing any manipulations in the xpath. 
Here goes my solution.

> Replace the default namespace 'xmlns= ' with 'xns='(or any other token
>   which wont be a possible conflict with any existing prefixes).After
>   entire processing is done with xDoc, before sending to service, update
>   it back to its previous state for avoiding any namespace related
>   issues from the service.

```
           if (xDoc.InnerXml.Contains("xmlns=\""))
                {
                    xDoc.InnerXml = xDoc.InnerXml.Replace("xmlns=\"", "xns=\"");
                }
```